# Why this question doesn't get answers?

Tags: support, questions, asking-questions, unanswered-questions

18 days ago I asked my [first quesiton](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/155051/how-can-i-record-stats-and-make-archivements) (about how to get records to make archivements) in this site but I notice that no one have answered it, and I don't know what to do.
I know that my question isn't too bad (or I think) because it doesn't have any downvote nor flag. But it also doesn't have any upvote, visits or answers.

I want to know what can I do in order to improve my question, so it may get an answer. The problem is that it's my first question in Game Development and my first game I am doing, so I both don't know how works exactly this SE (how to make good questions) nor I know what thing I am trying to ask, I'm new in this and I am not sure how to explain myself.

Do you  have any suggestion to improve my question itself or the way I wrote my question?

**P.S:** I'm sorry if this question isn't for Meta, I am also not sure if this can be asked on Meta, but some days ago an user suggest me to ask this if I doesn't get answers. If this isn't allowed, I'll delete the question inmediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good clue is the first comment:

> I'm not sure if I completely understand your question...

If other users have trouble understanding your question, they usually won't answer it. (Since you probably don't want answers from users who misunderstand the question)

It looks like your question outlines a viable approach to getting the behaviour you want. So the first point to clarify is: does your code work?

- **If it does not work**, try editing your question to describe the specific problem you've observed with your code that you're trying to fix.
- **If it does work**, then ask "what is it I want out of this question?"

  - Is there something about your current working code that you dislike, and want to improve?

    If so, try editing your question to describe this specific aspect you're unsatisfied with, and ask for ways to improve that aspect.
  - Are you concerned about the performance of this code?

    If so, try profiling the code to measure how big a problem it is (it might not be a problem at all), and identify what specific parts are the bottleneck. Then edit your question to describe those profiling results and ask for ways to fix the bottleneck.
  - Are you just curious about whether you're approaching it the "right"/"accepted" way?

    In my opinion, this doesn't make a good Q&A question - no users here are the arbiters of what implementation of a feature is "right." If the code works and you like working with it and it performs well, then it's "right enough" no matter what someone on the Internet says. ;)

    If you really want open-ended feedback on your code, you can try the Code Review StackExchange instead.